# Proving a Space of Real Valued sequences is Banach.

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

> **Theorem:** A normed vector space $(V,||\circ||)$ is a banach space if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ in $V$ with the property that $\sum ||x_n||<\infty$ we have $\sum x_n < \infty$.
>
> **Question:** Let $L=\{x=(x_n) \subset \mathbb R: \sum |x_n|<\infty\}$ and $||x||=\sum |x_n|,\forall x \in L$. Prove that $(L,||\circ||)$ is a banach space.

So I would guess that I should use the above theorem to solve this problem. So suppose we have $v_n \in L$ and $\sum ||v_n|| < \infty $ then we need to show that $\sum v_n < \infty$ but what does $\sum v_n < \infty$ mean where each $v_n$ is a sequence. How do we sum a series of sequences?

Comment: Easy: exactly as we sum functions, i.e. pointwise.

Comment: So if $x_n=1,\forall n$ and $x_m=2,\forall m$ then $x_n+x_m=x_k=3 ,\forall k$

Comment: I don't like your notation, but you are right. For me, $\{x_n\}_n=\{x_m\}_m$. You can't distinguish different sequences by using different indices. It is the same with functions: $f(x)$ and $f(t)$ are the *same* function $f$.

Comment: Cool thanks, just for the sake of correctness:  if $x_n=1,\forall n$ and $y_n=2,\forall n$ then $x_n+y_n=3 ,\forall n$

Comment: Sure. In general the sum of $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ is the sequence $\{x_n+y_n\}_n$.

Comment: Sorry, but there's some very bad notation in the question. If my $V$ is the space of all potatos equipped with the $+$ operation, what does it mean that a potato $y=\sum x_n$ satisfies $y<\infty$?

Comment: Do you mean that $\sum v_n < \infty$ is badly defined?

Comment: @Gottfried It is _not_ defined. On the LHS there's a vector and on the RHS there's a (generalized) number.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to use the theorem above but it got very complicated and instead I've tried to use the completeness of $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $l_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L$. Then we have $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N \in \mathbb N \ such \ that\ n,m>N \Rightarrow ||l_n-l_m||<\epsilon$$ So by the reverse triangle inequality we have $$| \ ||l_n||-||l_m||\ | \leq ||l_n-l_m||<\epsilon$$ which implies $||l_n||$ is cauchy in $\mathbb R$ and therefore converges to some $k \in \mathbb R$.

Let $(k_n)=K$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $\sum |k_n|=k$. Clearly $K \in L$ so we just need to show that $l_n \rightarrow K$.

Is this correct so far? If anybody could show me how the last step is done that would be great. I've been trying for a while but can't seem to do it.